# Configuring dependabot to access Github Packages repository

Tags: github, npm, dependabot, github-packages

I'm trying to use dependabot on a private github repo (let's call it `RepoA`. They're npm packages, and depend on other private github repos that I serve via Github Packages (let's call them `LibA` and `LibB`.

I read some blog posts and tried the following:

- Created a `dependabot.yml` file

```yaml
version: 2
registries:
  npm-github:
    type: npm-registry
    url: https://npm.pkg.github.com
    token: ${{secrets.MY_DEPENDABOT_TOKEN}}
    replaces-base: true
```

- Within my organization, I went to *Secrets and variables* -> *Dependabot* and added `MY_DEPENDABOT_TOKEN` to all my packages. Link: [https://github.com/organizations/[MY_ORGANIZATION]/settings/secrets/dependabot](https://github.com/organizations/%5BMY_ORGANIZATION%5D/settings/secrets/dependabot)
- Within my organization, I went to *Code security and analysis* -> *Grant Dependabot access to private repositories* and selected `RepoA`, `LibA` and `LibB`. Link: [https://github.com/organizations/[MY_ORGANIZATION]/settings/security_analysis](https://github.com/organizations/%5BMY_ORGANIZATION%5D/settings/security_analysis)

And still, when I try to run dependabot to generate a PR by itself, I get an warning, and while checking the log, I noticed this:

```
  proxy | 2023/10/25 19:52:55 [075] 401 https://npm.pkg.github.com:443/download/[MY_ORGANIZATION]/[MY_PACKAGE]/1.0.5/5c0cb9bfd2777ff51791408115241a26f694f8e9
  proxy | 2023/10/25 19:52:55 [075] {"error":"authentication token not provided"}
```

What am I missing? How can i grant authorization for dependabot to work with and download my private packages?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered two things that were missing.

The first thing is that `dependabot.yml`, if using the embeded github version, should be placed inside `.github` folder.

The second one is that you need to check your npm / yarn / pnpm configuration files and setup them properly. The following blog post describes how to do it:

https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/working-with-dependabot/guidance-for-the-configuration-of-private-registries-for-dependabot

#### npm

You need to add the registry to the `.npmrc` file:

```
@myscope:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
```

#### yarn berry

You need to add the registry to the `.yarnrc.yml` file:

```yaml
npmScopes:
  YOUR-ORG:
    npmAlwaysAuth: true
    npmRegistryServer: "https://npm.pkg.github.com"
```